# VBA Remove Space Before Paragraph

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, office-automation

I am using excel vba with word object library to copy-paste a range in a word document.

```
wordSelection.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, WordFormatting:=False, RTF:=False
```

I need to keep my Excel formating.

The problem reside in the fact that word add spaces between the lines of my copied table.
The only way I've found to remove them is manually  via word document "Line and Paragraph Spacing" on the dropdown "Remove Space Before Paragraph"

That's what I have :

[image: The display to avoid]

Should be turned into this :

[image: The result awaited]

After searching, I found these parameters that should resolve my problem but It doen't work.

```
Selection.ParagraphFormat.Space1
Selection.ParagraphFormat.SpaceBefore = 0
Selection.ParagraphFormat.LineUnitAfter = 0
Selection.ParagraphFormat.CloseUp
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You need to show examples of what the copied text is and how you want it to look.  When you grab the screen shots from Word, make sure that you are displaying all formatting marks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
wordSelection.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
```